# add global revision number in php source files

Tags: php, svn

I want to replace a global revision no (head) in my PHP source files whenever I make a checkin (or update)

for example I have below code

```
<?php 

print 'Rv no : $glbRevisionNumber$';

?>
```

in all the php files that have under one folder eg. myapp/* the $glbRevisionNumber$ should get replaced with the current head revision number.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: *(reference)* [SVN Redbook: Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at svn pre-commit-hooks:

http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook

Here are some example scripts:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/

Answer (score -1):

Create a pre-commit hook in your version control system that does a replace of  $glbRevisionNumber$ in every committed file.